# Have qdap amplifiers apply to negated words

Tags: r, qdap

R 3.4.3, using `qdap::polarity()`, I'm wondering if there is a way to have an amplifier apply to a negated word instead of the actual word itself. In the example below, "love" is the positive word, "didn't" is the negation word, and "definitely" is the amplification word. I want to have phrase "a" have a more negative polarity score, but it appears "definitely" is amplifying "love" and not "didn't love".

```
library(qdap)
text <- c("definitely didn't love", "didn't love", "love")
phrase <- c("a", "b", "c")
df <- data.frame(phrase, text)
polarity(df$text, df$phrase)

  phrase total.sentences total.words ave.polarity sd.polarity stan.mean.polarity
1      a               1           3       -0.115          NA                 NA
2      b               1           2       -0.707          NA                 NA
3      c               1           1        1.000          NA                 NA
```

Thanks in advance,
-jt

Comment: If you use the `SentimentAnalysis` package, you may get what you want. `foo <- analyzeSentiment(df$text); foo` gives me 0.33, 0.5, and 1.0 for `SentimentQDAP` in the output.

Comment: unfortunately, SentimentQDAP is just treating "definitely" as a neutral word and lowering the score for the third word. "monkey didn't love" would give me the same score.

Comment: I see. Hope someone can help you out.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: Thanks Tyler...I'll provide a little more detailed explanation in the answer, please let me know if I don't explain this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way `qdqp::polarity` works. The valence words can amplify, deamplify, or negate/reverse the tagged polarized word only. For example, the phrase "definitely didn't love" from the question above contains `<amplifier> <negator> <polarized word>`. 
The negator "didn't", reverses the positively polarized word "love".
The amplifier "definitely" amplifies the positive polarized word "love". It does not amplify the negated "didn't love".